# How to obtain WSO2 docker-compose distribution from a previous release

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

When you are going to download a distribution of WSO2 product, for the lastest release is possible to download different distributions (binary, msi installer, docker, docker-compose, helm, kubernetes, etc.) but when you try to do it from a previous release, there is only binary and OS's installers (ubuntu, mac, windows, etc).

But I would like to download, for instance docker-compose distribution for the previous version.
How then can it be possible to do?

This images show it clearly:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have checked that the URL generated for the latest version can be modified and can be selected other previous versions. For instance, for downloading AM version 3.1.0, previous to the latest release (v 3.2.0), can be downloaded for docker compose in this manner:

[http://product-dist.wso2.com/downloads/api-manager/3.1.0/instruction-pages/subscription/docker-compose/docker-apim-3.1.0.zip](http://product-dist.wso2.com/downloads/api-manager/3.2.0/instruction-pages/subscription/docker-compose/docker-apim-3.2.0.zip)

WSO2 should leave available all these links explicitly referred to in the previous versions.

Answer (score 1):

You can get these artifacts from the docker-apim repo. https://github.com/wso2/docker-apim/tree/v3.1.0.3

Comment: It is Ok also, but it is not the distribution itself. You have to do extra build steps to do it properly, and I want the "official" release. Thanks anyway.